# How to add a "Base SDK" in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, ios4, sdk, xcode4

I currently use XCode 4.0 with Base SDK 4.3.

I would like to compile my app with an older SDK, for example 4.2, but I don't have this possibility as I have no other choice than SDK 4.3.

Do you know how to add older SDKs than the default Base SDK 4.3 proposed ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'd like to know this as well...

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860305/adding-an-old-sdk-to-xcode-4

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. Xcode versions are released along with iOS SDK's. They are linked together i.e particular Xcode version can compile the code on the specific iOS SDK only (which it come with by default).
To compile your code in lower version of SDK, you need to download the lower version of Xcode

Answer (score -1):

by changing the iosdeployment target you can run this.

for this,
 go to the targets in the xcode and get the info .There you can find the second tab build.in that you have search field.type the ios deployment target.change that to 4.2.So that it can run on 4.2 also

Comment: Thanks for your answer Babji. Nevertheless I want to change the Base SDK, not the deployment target (which is defined to 3.2 in my case). Somebody knows how to do that ?

Comment: Is it possible to open this question up again? Not sure of the protocol on that and I know that "me too" answers are generally frowned upon.

Comment: you can change it in the Build settings

Answer (score -1):

In build settings, under Architechtures, you have something called as Base SDK .. you can change you base SDK there and set it to the latest ios version you have installed.