# where to find and install older iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Simulator SDK 4.3 to Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651773/install-simulator-sdk-4-3-to-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion)

I need to install older iOS SDK but I could only find the XCode and SDK bundles at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#. Is there anyway to work around that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Simulator SDK 4.3 to Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651773/install-simulator-sdk-4-3-to-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783308/adding-older-ios-sdks-to-xcode-4-1-in-lion, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860305/adding-an-old-sdk-to-xcode-4, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320235/is-there-a-way-to-install-older-ios-sdks-in-xcode

Answer (score 7):

The reason why there is no obvious work around is because Apple wants you to develop in the latest SDK while targeting iOS versions/devices as far back as you'd need.

Sometimes, it can be preferable to have an older SDK though. I too was faced with this problem when I upgraded to Xcode 4.5, suddenly 2 of my frameworks stopped working due to the new SDK. I could not upgrade the frameworks to a newer version since the cost of development was already made.

Download an older Xcode version (the one with the desired SDK) from the link you provided in your answer. Each folder in

> Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/

is a separate SDK. Copy and paste the folder in your Xcode installation (same directory as stated above) and you have installed the older SDK. I'd suggest you save this SDK seperatly somewhere, because - if I'm not mistaking - older SDK's get removed from Xcode at updates.

Comment: I couldn't single out the SDK bits from the Xcode and SDK bundle installed from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#, any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can download few older SDK in your XCode 4.x:
XCode > Preferences > Downloads > Components > Choose and install what you want.

Comment: Yes, he mentioned that.  His question is about how to install them.

Comment: @CodaFi: No, I mean the local XCode application menu, not the webpage.

Comment: Perhaps he meant a broader range of SDK's than Xcode's offerings of iOS 5.1+  it really is quite sad that Apple is deliberately refusing access to deprecated SDKs

Comment: Yes, it's sad, but I have XCode 4.5 and I can install iOS 4.3  and 5.0 too. The devices, which are not upgradeable to 4.3 are quite old ones.

Comment: No "Downloads" under preferences anymore (Xcode 7) :(